# PHP session destroy function does not work in Opera

Tags: php, session

I made a login system in PHP and every thing working fine in **Google Chrome** and **Mozilla**. But in  **Opera** when I click sign out then it works fine and after that if I press back button in browser then it comes to the previous page (`profile page`) and shows the contents in that page even if I logout but if I refresh the page then sessions are destroy properly. I used the following code for `session destroy`

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
session_unset();
```

I am in a critical stage please help me with a right advise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason is probably because Opera caches the page and when you go back you hit the cached version.

Comment: @Jesperhag well, this also occurs in Moz and Chrome!

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">

Comment: @NirobHasan And that (what Jesperhag said) usually isn't a problem. You could have a piece of Javascript which executes on DOMContentLoaded which redirects you to a login page if there's no cookie.

Comment: How does JS know whether there is a cookie? I mean we are setting the http only flag right? right? :)

Comment: can you just `var_dump($_SESSION);` in the page you logout? just check what comes as output before you logout and after you logout and come back to that page. check if it shows the same values!

Comment: Please [refer to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), which provides the code needed with relevant information explaining the issue of the cookie session ID.

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION) does not work @praveen. Please anyone give me a valid solution.

Comment: why it wont work :O and thats not a solution..its just for debugging purposes. does it work with user logged in?

Comment: In which page I can use these? @HMarioD

Comment: It works properly when I logged in but does not work when I logged out. @praveen

Comment: which shows the natural behaviour. its the way opera works with cache i guess and u can use those lines by @HMarioD inside your head tag.

Comment: Insert in the <head> section of page you don't want to be cached.

Comment: Omg, please post the "cache" comment as answer, combine with "meta tag" no-cache comment, up-vote that answer and move on.. Pointless..

Comment: @dbf, sorry, is form me? you want I put my comment as an answer?

Comment: @HMarioD the combination of the two yea, and in order to test "meta no-cache", most likely the OP has first to empty his browser cache in Opera in order to prevent any caching ..

Answer (score 0):

Insert in the head section of page you don't want to be cached.

```
<meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="0">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```